# Можно ли в Linux делать асинхронные вызовы одного и того-же сокета не защищая его?

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность, синхронизация

Доброго времени суток. Пишу клиент-серверное приложение на С++ под Linux. Суть следующая. Есть один открытый сокет и две переменные, хранящие его дескрптор.
У меня очень большие входящий и исходящий потоки. Можно ли мне одновременно производить чтение и запись в этом сокете с разных потоков, не используя мьютекса и любых других элементов синхронизации?

Comment: В общем случае НЕТ. Сокет это поток, ты не можешь контролировать кто сколько вычитал, т.е. может получиться так, что первый поток вычитает байты с 1 по 10, а потом вклинется второй и прочитает с 11 по 15, когда первый поток решит что-то еще прочитать он понятия иметь не будет в каком состояние находится поток. Но если смотреть с точки зрения упадет/не упадет, то ответ - программа не упадет, но такая фигня при чтение будет :)

Comment: Тут подразумевается что один - читает, другой - пишет, или как?

Comment: @VTT да. (дополнительные слова что бы было >10)

Comment: Если один поток читает, а другой пишет, то должно быть все хорошо (но всегда можно сделать хуже - например, один поток может поменять настройки сокета).

Comment: @KoVadim на эти действия уже можно закрыться мьютексом. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: для многопоточного чтения можно использовать recv с флагом MSG_PEEK, recv в этом случае будет возвращать количество данных в сокете, не изменяя сами данные. Однако непосредственно получать данные следует закрыв эту операцию блокировкой, чтобы данные не считали другие потоки (как указал ffk).

Comment: @goldstar_labs спасибо.